# Statistics in python with missing values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a huge dataset with something like 23 columns. I want to do descriptive statistics on the column 18 (and many others), but there are many missing values. I am wondering if there exist a command like in SAS to compute the statistics if the cell is not a missing value. In the picture I provide, i'd like to compute descriptive statistics for columns 1,2,5

I have a least 1 N/A in each column so i can't delete the N/A.

[My dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzHx8.png)

I tried the following

```
import numpy 
numpy.nanmean(df_14,axis=18)
```

But it did not work. I am new using Python by the way.

Thxs,

Comment: If you're using a dataframe then you can take the mean with `df.mean()` (where `df` is your dataframe). Pandas ignores NaNs by default when taking the mean https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html

Comment: There's also `df.describe` which can be convenient if you quickly want to collect a bunch of descriptive statistics.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It worked pretty fine.

Answer (score 0):

`df.describe()` would do the trick.

Pandas ignores NaN values by default when calculating descriptive statistics.

Example: taken straight from https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'categorical': pd.Categorical(['d','e','f']),
...                    'numeric': [1, 2, 3],
...                    'object': ['a', 'b', 'c']
...                   })
>>> df.describe()   
       numeric
count      3.0
mean       2.0
std        1.0
min        1.0
25%        1.5
50%        2.0
75%        2.5
max        3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ "a": [1,2,3,4,5],
                  "b":[5,4,3,2,24],
                  "c":[52,45,32,62,24]})
```

When you want to get statistics use `df.describe()`:

```
              a        b          c
count  5.000000   5.0000   5.000000
mean   3.000000   7.6000  43.000000
std    1.581139   9.2358  15.231546
min    1.000000   2.0000  24.000000
25%    2.000000   3.0000  32.000000
50%    3.000000   4.0000  45.000000
75%    4.000000   5.0000  52.000000
max    5.000000  24.0000  62.000000
```

If you want to have information about your dataset use `df.info()`:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns (total 3 columns):
a    5 non-null int64
b    5 non-null int64
c    5 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(3)
memory usage: 200.0 bytes
None
```